# I am planning to visit Iran for a week with my family but I am concerned about security after reading Trump's tweet

Tags: trains, safety, event-based-effects, iran

I am planning to visit Iran next month.
Yesterday I saw Trump's tweet about time for change for Iran and I read a bit about the anti-government movement there.

So, how safe a 10 day trip in Iran for me, my pregnant wife and 2 year old son?

Should I cancel my trip or are there dos and donts you can advise?

Also I wonder whether I will have problems with American visa after this trip.

P.S. I am planning to go through Georgia by train to Baku and then by plane to Tehran.

Comment: What Passports do you hold?

Comment: The best thing is to look at your own national foreign office advice. For instance in the UK this is https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/iran. If there is advice against travelling to specific regions and you ignore it you may invalidate your insurance.

Comment: If I were you, I would not travel to Iran within the next two months :)

Comment: @Meysam why do you say so ?

Comment: Well, that's only my gut feeling that many things will go wrong within the next two months based on my understanding of past events. But I have no proof for that and you can simply ignore my advice.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38441/which-are-safe-and-unsafe-regions-in-iran

Answer (score 6):

My first thought was "which tweet?" as there have been so many of them.

But as someone living in the US and following what Trump tweets, I would take anything he tweets with a huge grain of sand (maybe even a whole beach or two).

I don't know what the political/social situation is in Iran (other than what I see in the news here and that there is possibly a general feeling of unrest), so I can't attest to how safe you and your family would be during your trip.  That is up to you to decide.

**However I would say that no tweet of Trump's is going to change what the current situation in Iran is**

In general (in my personal opinion - others may disagree with me) what Trump tweets is rhetoric designed to appeal to his voter base and not to cause change in other countries.

As for your second question about the US visa.  In general just visiting Iran will not be cause for a visa refusal.  It may cause more scrutiny of your application (but I am not a State Dept employee - so I don't really know).  I just googled it and there are many people who visit Iran and then visit the US without an issue.

The only issue is if there is some obvious nefarious patterns in your travels that you need to explain (I was once a tourist in Syria - which was a great place to visit before the war, but going there now would be a huge red flag) , or if you are a national of the country de jour that is banned by the current administration from coming to the US (and even that seems to change daily based on court injunctions etc)

Comment: Also note that visiting Iran will make it impossible to visit the USA on the Visa Waiver Program. If you *need* a visa for the USA, or already have one, this may not be as big of an issue, but if you are, say, a German citizen who could otherwise just get an ESTA this could be a big burden.