# How can I open and reset the combination lock on my suitcase, I have forgotten the combination

Tags: usa, luggage

How can I reset the combination and open my suitcase? I have forgotten the origanal combination.

Comment: Is it the kind that has three or four wheels with letters or numbers?  There's always the brute force approach, if you're patient.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the suitcase model and how many digits the lock has? It might be helpful.

Comment: There’s a detailed description of what to do here https://barcelonalowdown.com/how-unlock-your-suitcase-forgot-combination/ Haven’t tried it myself so can’t vouch for whether it works!

Comment: Not really a duplicate of [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76073/10051), but I have explained in details how to open it.

Answer (score 3):

Does the lock have the Travel Sentry logo on it?

[image: Travel Sentry logo]

Locks sold for the US market will have this logo along with a key slot for a TSA master key.

You can purchase a set of these master keys on eBay, Amazon, Wish, or many other shopping web sites around the world. The key with the code printed on your lock will open it. Or you can [3D print](https://github.com/Xyl2k/TSA-Travel-Sentry-master-keys) just the key you need, if you have a 3D printer.

Comment: Whilst this may well work, it's overkill for 99.9% of all suitcase combination locks which can be opened with no more than a few minutes of either brute force.

Comment: @Doc Oh, certainly brute force or some of the tricks you described will work. So I voted up your answer. Some people might not be comfortable with applying brute force to something of obviously relatively low quality though.

Comment: "Brute force" means trying every combination, not actually "forcing" anything. The quality of the lock doesn't come into it...

Answer (score 3):

Combination locks used on luggage are generally very poor quality, and not intended to do much more than keep out an opportunistic thief.

If you look somewhere like Youtube you will find countless videos that will show you how to open such locks.  The exact method will depend on the quality of the lock and how many digits it contains, but could be as simple as simply rolling through all possible combinations (especially if the lock only has 3 digits).

To do it a little quicker (especially for 4 digit locks) you can normally apply pressure somewhere on the lock and feel when the lock falls into place.  Again, the exact method will depend on the lock, so look on youtube to find one that is similar, and/or just follow the general advice given in these videos.

I recently found a 4-digit combination lock in the back of a rental car.  Despite being a reasonable quality lock, it took me about 30 seconds to open by simply moving the rollers and feeling for them to latch.